# RTCPeerConnection - "a Invalid SDP LINE" error in janus-Gateway. Help Me

Tags: webrtc, janus-gateway

Please contact janus gateway.

Currently, we have developed an "Business Online Video Meeting System" using janus gateway.

However, when creating a room and connecting more than 8 people to this room, Console.error appears as shown below,
The video of connected people does not appear.

When accessing the room, people send their PC desktop and webcam Video to the room,
The video can only be viewed by the room's administrator, and the video is not shared among connected people.

※ In other words, those who connect enter the Room with 3 streams, 2 Video and 1 Audio.

After that, if one person leaves the room and refreshes the browser of that room, the video will appear again.

I am wondering what is causing this problem and how to fix it.

---

```
[console.Error CASE1]
WebRTC error: DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to parse SessionDescription. a Invalid SDP line.
at RTCPeerConnection.r.RTCPeerConnection.<computed> [as setRemoteDescription]

[console.Error CASE1]
WebRTC error: DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote offer sdp: A BUNDLE group contains a 
MID='27' matching no m= section.

[console.Error CASE3]
WebRTC error: DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to parse SessionDescription. a=rtcp-fb:96 Invalid SDP line.
at RTCPeerConnection.r.RTCPeerConnection.<computed> [as setRemoteDescription]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into an issue that was recently fixed in janus where the SDP buffer was too small for the content and got truncated. See [here](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/issues/2791) for the relevant discussion and linked pull requests.

Comment: Thanks for the good comments.
Then, the cutoff phenomenon due to insufficient SDP buffer size in the current Janus Gateway is
Has the patch been fixed?

Where can I see that information?

※ I would like to know how to increase the SDP Buffer size.